# Async function in run() with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I'm searching a solution but it's always the same and she's not correpond to my problem.

I have a lot of route element but for all routes with different controller I need to know if the user is authenticate or not. If yes, I have a token from an api and if no, I have a token too. So I need to have a token from an api when I load all controllers.

So I don't want to make a resolve for each "when()", I don't want to ddos the API so I search a system like this with

```
app.run(['Auth', function(Auth){

// Call my service & waiting his resolve
// When resolved, continue the init

}]);
```

So how can I make a resolve system with my "Auth" service on the run() ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a service where you will have variable with status of authentication, inject this service in all controllers and in each controller call method of that service. Inside that method check variable with authentication status and only if authentication request was not yet send - send it (and set variable to status `sent`).